# PHP randomise file list array from existing code?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Working on creating a full screen slide show in a browser window

Have found these excellent two pieces of code over on javascriptkit

```
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/externalphp2.shtml
```

The php generates the array of image files, the javascript/css/html runs the show.

I have edited the css/html so that images fill the window. This part is not a problem.

I would like the php to generate a random list each time it is run. It seems that [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)($files); is the answer (?), but wherever I put it in the php file it don't work.

```
<? 
//PHP SCRIPT: getimages.php

Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");

//This function gets the file names of all images in the current directory
//and ouputs them as a JavaScript array
function returnimages($dirname=".") {
  $pattern="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$)"; //valid image extensions
  $files = array();
  $curimage=0;
  if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
      if(eregi($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image
        //Output it as a JavaScript array element
        echo 'galleryarray['.$curimage.']="'.$file .'";';
        $curimage++;
      }
    }

    closedir($handle);
  }
  return($files);
}

echo 'var galleryarray=new Array();'; //Define array in JavaScript
returnimages() //Output the array elements containing the image file names
?>
```

Can someone please help me shuffle the generated file list array ?

Thank you

html:

```
<script src="pics/getimages.php"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var curimg=0
function rotateimages(){
document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", "pics/"+galleryarray[curimg])
curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0
}

window.onload=function(){
setInterval("rotateimages()", 5000)
}
</script>

<div>
<img id="slideshow" src="pics/animal_0001.jpg" />
</div>
```

Output from original php file:

```
var galleryarray=new Array();
galleryarray[0]="nature_0001.jpg";
galleryarray[1]="animal_0107.jpg";
galleryarray[2]="nature_0007.jpg";
galleryarray[3]="nature_0083.jpg";
galleryarray[4]="animal_0120.jpg";
galleryarray[5]="nature_0025.jpg";
galleryarray[6]="summertime.jpg";
galleryarray[7]="nature_0091.jpg";
galleryarray[8]="travel_0018.jpg";
galleryarray[9]="animal_0052.jpg";
galleryarray[10]="travel_0038.jpg";
galleryarray[11]="animal_0047.jpg";
galleryarray[12]="nature_0016.jpg";
galleryarray[13]="nature_0024.jpg";
galleryarray[14]="travel_0053.jpg";
```

Output from your revision:

```
var galleryarray = true;
```

Treat:

http://www.tsah.co.uk/tsah/slide/slides.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over complicating things by building the JS yourself. Try [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
<?php

function returnimages($dirname=".") {
  $images = array(); 
  $pattern="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$)"; //valid image extensions
  if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
      if(eregi($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image
        $images[] = $file;
      }
    }

    closedir($handle);
  }
  return $images;
}

$images = returnimages();
shuffle($images);

Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
echo 'var galleryarray = ' . json_encode( $images ) . ';'; 
?>
```

[shuffle](http://php.net/shuffle) does not return the shuffled array, but the status of the operation (TRUE/FALSE).

Comment: Hi Sergui, thanks for the reply. I applied your revised code, but it just gives me a black screen after the first picture (which is set in the <img> html). I checked the output of getimages.php and no array is created ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, was returning `$files` instead of `$images`. Updated.

Comment: I checked php is at version 5.3 and json is enabled at version 1.21.

Comment: Thanks, but still getting blank/black screen, and still no array generated ? :(

Comment: Does the relevant javascript have anything to do with it? Now in OP

Comment: Yeah, turns out I did not properly read the docs for `shuffle`. Updated.

Comment: Brilliant, works perfectly. Thank you very much :) Treat at bottom of original post for a few days (might be a bit slow)